# my computer keeps typing 7 after everything i type into google

Tags: windows-7

So I'll type something into Google and its fine but after I press enter and the page loads into Google, the number 7 appears after what I type. No matter what I type into Google the number 7 appears. I already tried cleaning out the key 7, and it didn't work. It's on my dell laptop with windows 7. Also it only happens on Google on Google Chrome. I run 1 extension called Ad block plus

Comment: Can you provide more info about your system? OS, browser, laptop/pc? what kind of keyboard do you use? is it wired/wireless? usb? etc... Anything you have will help.

Comment: well i have laptop and its a dell laptop with windows 7. and its just on google nothing else. and it only happens on Google chrome

Comment: Any extensions you run in google chrome?

Comment: I run adblock plus but thats it

Comment: Try Pulling the battery for a while then put it back. If it still persists maybe something is wrong with chrome. I advise uninstalling it and reinstalling it to see if the issue persists.

Comment: Is `7` in text box only? or in the URL also (e.g. `search?q=foobar7`)?